# Can I use a button with an event handler to send the user to a different xaml sceen?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a Memory Game with a start menu, and a separate page where the game takes place. On the main menu you can select your theme and press a button to go to the game. I also have a button on the game screen, but I can not figure out how to make it link to the main menu.

I honestly don't know how to go about doing this.

This is the button that links from the main page to the game(in the xaml):

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Padding="25" Click="Play_Clicked" Background="#FF0E0E0E" Foreground="#FFF3FF00" FontSize="18">Start Game</Button>
```

this is the code in xaml.cs:

```
private void Play_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var startMenu = DataContext as StartMenuViewModel;
            startMenu.StartNewGame(categoryBox.SelectedIndex);
        }
```

This is the code from "StartMenuViewModel" that contains the "StartNewGame":

```
public void StartNewGame(int categoryIndex)
{
    var category = (SlideCategories)categoryIndex;
    GameViewModel newGame = new GameViewModel(category);
    _mainWindow.DataContext = newGame;
}
```

This code works, does anyone know how to make a similar button to go from the game screen to the main menu?

Comment: Put a frame in your MainWindow and implement navigation where you load a different XAML page based on the user's choice.

Comment: My advice. Don't put a frame in your window. Don't use pages. Don't write datatemplate selectors. Use usercontrols and associate them with viewmodel type in datatemplates. This is a very common pattern in commercial wpf development, called viewmodel first. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most lightweight way opposed to using a `Frame`, is to create a view model for each page. Then create a main view model which holds all pages and manages their selection. A `ContentControl` will display the view models using a `DataTemplate` assigned to the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property or in a multi page scenario either a `DataTemplateSelector` assigned to `ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector` or implicit templates by only defining the `DataTemplate.DataType` without the `Key` attribute:

## The View

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <!-- 
        The templates for the view of each page model.
        Can be moved to dedicated files.
    -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type PageA}">
      <Border Background="Coral">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type PageB}">
      <Border Background="DeepSkyBlue">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>    
  </Window.Resources>


<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Load Page A"
            Command="{Binding SelectPageFromIndexCommand}"
            CommandParameter="0" />
    <Button Content="Load Page B"
            Command="{Binding SelectPageFromIndexCommand}"
            CommandParameter="1" />

    <!-- The actual page control -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

## The View Model

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.Pages = new ObservableCollection<IPage>() {new PageA() {Title = "Page A"}, new PageB() {Title = "Page B"}};

    // Show startup page
    this.SelectedPage = this.Pages.First();
  }

  // Define the Execute and CanExecute delegates for the command
  // and pass to constructor
  public ICommand SelectPageFromIndexCommand => new SelectPageCommand(
    param => this.SelectedPage = this.Pages.ElementAt(int.Parse(param as string)),
    param => int.TryParse(param as string, out int index));

  private IPage selectedPage;    
  public IPage SelectedPage
  {
    get => this.selectedPage;
    set
    {
      if (object.Equals(value, this.selectedPage))
      {
        return;
      }

      this.selectedPage = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<IPage> pages;    
  public ObservableCollection<IPage> Pages
  {
    get => this.pages;
    set
    {
      if (object.Equals(value, this.pages))
      {
        return;
      }

      this.pages = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**SelectPageCommand.cs**

```
class SelectPageCommand : ICommand
{
  public SelectPageCommand(Action<object> executeDelegate, Predicate<object> canExecuteDelegate)
  {
    this.ExecuteDelegate = executeDelegate;
    this.CanExecuteDelegate = canExecuteDelegate;
  }

  private Predicate<object> CanExecuteDelegate { get; }
  private Action<object> ExecuteDelegate { get; }

  #region Implementation of ICommand

  public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => this.CanExecuteDelegate?.Invoke(parameter) ?? false;

  public void Execute(object parameter) => this.ExecuteDelegate?.Invoke(parameter);

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
  }

  #endregion
}
```

## The Page Models

**IPage.cs**

```
// Base type for all pages
interface IPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**PageA.cs**

```
// IPage implementation. 
// Consider to introduce dedicated interface IPageA which extends IPage
class PageA : IPage
{
  public string Title { get; set; }

  // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

**PageB.cs**

```
// IPage implementation. 
// Consider to introduce dedicated interface IPageB which extends IPage
class PageB : IPage
{
  public string Title { get; set; }

  // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```